# Transfer Mii from Wii U to the virtual Wii on the same console

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u

I spent many hours crafting the perfect Mii for my Wii U console.  Then I run the virtual Wii mode on that console.  I was hoping my Mii would appear there too, but it doesn't.  Is there any way to copy the Mii from the Wii U mode to the Wii mode on the same console?

Note: There are a lot of similar questions on here about transferring Miis from a physical Wii to/from a Wii U console, or virtual Wii, but I can't find a question that refers to transferring Miis between the two modes on the same console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's impossible. About as impossible as transferring a Mii from a 3DS to a Wii is.

The reason for this, is that 3DS and Wii U Miis have features that do not exist on the Wii, such as additional hairstyles.

According to [Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/01/19/3ds-can-import-your-wii-mii-too-robust-to-export-them-back/):

> But what if you want to send a Mii back to the Wii? "It's a one way transfer," NOA Product Marketing Manager Bill Trinen told Joystiq. "You can send your Miis from your Wii to your 3DS. But, because the Mii Maker on the Nintendo 3DS is a more robust program and has newer features, like hairstyles and eyes and things like that, the Miis you create there can't go back to the Wii."

The same holds for the Wii U as well.

Unless Nintendo updates the Wii's Mii channel to add those features, there won't be any way to transfer Miis back to the Wii. Since the Wii has been replaced by the Wii U, such an update most likely won't see the day either.